# Zingchart wordcloud: How to stop showing both uppercase and lowercase of the same word

Tags: javascript, visualization, word-cloud, zingchart

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jbwL9tc0/

Code:

```
var myConfig = {
"graphset":[
    {
        "type":"wordcloud",
        "options":{
            "text":"Please welcome John to the company. Please welcome Jane to the company. Welcome Bob. Welcome Amy. Welcome Kim.",
            "min-length": 3,           
            "ignore": ["the"]
        }
    }
]
```

};

Result: Both "welcome" and "Welcome" are shown in the cloud.

Is there a way to display only one of the same word? E.g. If "Welcome" exists, ignore "welcome". Or count "welcome" towards "Welcome" but hide it in the cloud.

Comment: You probably have to preprocess and normalize the strings yourself. How do we differentiate between case values efficiently. What about welcome vs welCome, or other typos? Do we normalize everything to the first token we find? As in, if we find first "welcome" and then "Welcome" we show "welcome"? and the other way round? Can you think of a situation in which two words are really different? As in Carry (name) vs carry.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!